# How can I add spacing between buttons while using btn-group-justified?

Tags: css, less

I'm using bootstrap's class

```
  <div class="btn-group btn-group-justified">
```

Buttons are perfect the way they are (I need them equally spaced and taking full length) but I would like a little space between them. I tried playing around with margins, width percentage and padding with no success.

Please see this codepen http://codepen.io/crhistian/pen/WwyWYM?editors=0100

Comment: If you want space between them, put them inside two div's with class 'col-md-6'

Answer (score 3):

**HTML**

```
<div class="panel-footer">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-2">
      <div class="row custom-row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <button class="btn btn-info btn-block">Cart</button>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <button class="btn btn-success btn-block">Checkout</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.custom-row {
  margin-left: -5px;
  margin-right: -5px;
}
.custom-row .col-md-6 {
  padding-left: 5px;
  padding-right: 5px;
}
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply! I actually had something similar and it looked OK on Firefox but was cutting off the lettering on checkout when I used Chrome. Unfortunately its on a pretty prominent area so I have to find a better work around

Comment: Can u attach a screenshot?

Comment: Here's an album http://imgur.com/a/wZRUs. The first picture is with my initial question, would look great if I could just add some spacing. The second is your solution on a small screen, also looks great and the third is your solution on a larger screen. You can see that the checkout text is cut off

Comment: Then you have to customize the bootstrap grid. I have updated the code.

Answer (score 0):

For the first button in the div tag

```
.btn-group {
float: left;
width: 45%;
}
```

And for your other button (add "2" to the other buttons div tag class):

```
.btn-group2 {
float: right;
width: 45%;
}
```

Then you can add margins for the same classes if you want to position them better

Comment: Why not rather use `:first-child` or `:last-child`? Styling for specific elements is rather rough, and using numbered classes is even much rougher.